# No arg constructor and De serialization in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, serializable

`DeSerialization` using the `Serializable` interface mechanism uses `Reflection` to `deserialize` the Object bytes to Object. But default `no arg constructor` is not called during this process and hence its not needed. But all the frameworks like `Spring,Hibernate` etc need `no arg constructor` even though they use Reflection. Isn't this contradictory or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The builtin standard deserialization does not use standard reflection to create instances.

Standard reflection can not create instances without calling a constructor (not necessarily the no arg constructor). So any framework only using standard reflection will need to call a constructor for instance creation.

To create instances without calling a constructor you need some kind of jvm-vendor specific extension, like `Unsafe`. It is up to the framework developers to use these extensions, many decide against it. (XStream https://x-stream.github.io/faq.html is the only i am aware of that actually uses it)

Comment: On the other hand the super class no-arg constructor is called... you confirm?

Comment: All constructors (except on `java.lang.Object`) will call another constructor (either super class, or one on the same class)

Comment: @CodeScale not sure what you mean with "on the other hand". Standard serialization doesnt call any constructors, the instances just comes into existence.

Comment: Only talk  during deserialization.. not during normal usage of objects creation

Comment: @CodeScale no constructor of the superclass is called during standard/builtin deserialization

Comment: Hmm...except if superclass is not serializable .. isn't it ?

Comment: @k5_Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by Standard Reflection and non Standard Reflection? So Deserialization uses non Standard Reflection?

Comment: @ghostrider not sure what exactly is used. It is a jvm builtin functionality. So it can use anything. But it can not use only standard reflection, because that does not provide enough functionality.